# Change parent width on input child typing CSS only

Tags: css

Is there a way to change parent width when ONLY input is target, not button.

I have tried `:focus-within` it works perfectly but when I click on button it also changes width because its within parent.

I also tried setting `pointer-events: none` on button.

What I want:
When I first click on button don't resize parent width, only when input is in target, or only when I start typing, whatever.

I also tried with `:placeholder-shown`

```css
.search-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width:40%;
  transition: width .5s ease-in;
}

.search-input {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  height:40px;
}

.search-button {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/*Make this to work*/
.search-wrapper:focus-within {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-wrapper">
  <input class="search-input" type="text" placeholder="search ....">
  <button class="search-button">
    Button
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: See here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_animated_search.asp

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner not what I want. There's no button

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by doing following tweaks. Although not the exact solution you are searching for since there is no parent selector to style parent based on child selector but it may help you out there.

```css
.search-wrapper { position: relative; width:60%; transition: width .5s ease-in; } .search-input { border: 2px solid blue; width: 100%; height:40px; } 
.search-button { 
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
left: -55px;
top: 9px;
transform: translateY(-50%); } /*Make this to work*/ 
.input-wrapper{ width: 50%;
display:inline-block;
transition: width .5s ease-in;}
.input-wrapper:focus-within { width: 70%; }
```

```html
<div class="search-wrapper">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input class="search-input" type="text" placeholder="search       ....">
  </div>
  <button class="search-button">
    Button
  </button>
</div>
```